# How to assign a var value to jQuery .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get value from `checkFields` method and then I assign it to hidden variable `searchValidate`. The value of `atleastOneFilled` will be `true` or `false` .Below is the code

```
var atleastOneFilled = checkFields($("#searchForm"));
alert('atleastOneFilled' + atleastOneFilled );
$('#searchValidate').val(atleastOneFilled);
```

But the value is not getting set to `searchValidate`. The alert displays the correct value but still not assigned to `searchValidate`. Is it something a wrong way of assigning to `.val()`

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" th:name="searchValidate"/>
```

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: What type of field is `#searchValidate`?

Comment: What kind of element is `#searchValidate`?

Comment: How do you check that it is not assigned?

Comment: I have edited the question with HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is happening because you are using id selector in jQuery to set the value and the input element is missing the id attribute.
So please change the html as shown below and it will work

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="searchValidate" th:name="searchValidate"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use a different jquery selector:

```
$('input[name="searchValidate"]').val(atLeastOneField);
```

the `#` signifies the `id` property of an element

Comment: Thanks. I have added id attribute

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't select when attributes contain `":"` you need to use foreach loop and match attributes .

```
 var atleastOneFilled = checkFields($("#searchForm"));
    alert('atleastOneFilled' + atleastOneFilled );

$( "input[type='hidden']" ).each(function(){

if($( "input" ).attr("th:name")="searchValidate")
{
    $('#searchValidate').val(atleastOneFilled);  

}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try

```
$('#searchValidate').text(atleastOneFilled);
```

instead of

```
$('#searchValidate').val(atleastOneFilled);
```